# In Jquery when tab key is continously pressed, cursor is getting stuck in the masked control

Tags: jquery

There are many custom masked controls(Datecontrol,Phone control,ZipCode control) and in- built controls(Textbox,Checkbox,Dropdownlist) in our screen. So when we press tab key continously, the cursor gets stuck on the masked controls only, and its does not moves to next control. Instead its moving back and forth on the masked control.

Below is the .cshtml code where the cursor is getting stuck, in any one control once we continously press tab key

```
 <table width="100%" class="noBorderTable">
     <tr>
         <td style="width: 17%" align="left">
             Primary
         </td>
         <td style="width: 33%">
             @Html.PhoneTextFor(m => Model.Insured_Primary, new { style = "width:84%;font-size:13px", maxlength = "20", title = "Phone" })
         </td>
         <td style="width: 17%" align="right">
             Alternate
         </td>
         <td style="width: 33%">
             @Html.PhoneTextFor(m => Model.Insured_Alternate, new { style = "width:84%;font-size:13px", maxlength = "20", title = "AlternatePhone" })
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Can you please help us with above issue?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a jQuery issue, the ability to tab from one html element to another is supported in all major browsers without using javascript.

What does the html source output look like for the razor code you've provided?

In order for the tab index to work correctly, you must specify a tab index attribute `<input type="text"  tabindex="1"/>` on each element. The index value specifies the 'tabbing' order.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: Problem is not related to tabindex,problem is when we keep tab key pressed for a while then cursor moves from one masked control to another masked control and at some point in time cursor gets stuck in one of the masked control only (any masked control) and does not move forward. Now even after release of tab key we try to click on another control the focus does not move from that control to any other control on the screen. Also the cursor continuously moves from first position to last position of that masked control itself (i.e. It continuously traverses through the length of that control).